# Axlsx ignores image.start_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, axlsx

Just a small problem that i'm facing with `axlsx_rails` images.
currently i have this:

```
sheet.add_image(:image_src => img, :noSelect => false, :noMove => false) do |image|
      image.start_at 5, 5
      image.end_at 15, 20 
  end
```

and it seems to somehow ignore the `image.start_at` line. No matter what values i give it, the image starts from 0,0 (Cell A1) and stretches until the values specified in `image.end_at`.
Does anyone know what could be causing this or how to get around it ? I need to simply put the image inside 3 merged cells.

Comment: And what about the end at? Have you tried passing the cell itself, like: `start_at: "E5"` ? These cells are merged?

Comment: end_at seems to work. I tried passing the cell itself but it doesn't affect it, regardless of whether the cells are merged or not.