# Axlsx seems to ignore image.start_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, axlsx

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38769065/axlsx-ignores-image-start-at/43887372#43887372) with the same problem I'm running into.

Unfortunately I didn't found an answer to this and couldn't aks in the original post. Maybe someone can help me my code looks like:

```
 img = File.expand_path(Rails.root+'app/assets/images/scb_footer_logo.png')
 sheet.add_image(:image_src => img) do |image|
     image.start_at 6,6
     image.end_at 6,6
 end
```

It seems to me it would ignore the start_at because it always starts at A1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem:

```
img = File.expand_path(Rails.root+'app/assets/images/scb_footer_logo.png')
sheet.add_image(:image_src => img, :start_at => [0,41], :end_at => [2, 44]) do |image|
    image.start_at 0, 41
    image.end_at 2,44
end
```

The trick is to define it in the add_image line and in the block.